# Using unknown data type FLOAT

Tags: mysql, npm, migration

I have written a migration to create a table using npm db-migrate and used mysql as the database.

[Screenshot of the warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRjqD.png)The migrations are running properly and the columns are being populated in the tables

```
column_A: {type: 'float', notNull: false},
column_B: {type: 'float', notNull: false},
column_C: {type: 'float', notNull: false},
column_D: {type: 'float', notNull: false},
```

but the console shows the following warning:

```
[WARN] Using unknown data type FLOAT
```

Can someone please help. Thanks!

Comment: What are the values you try to insert in these FLOAT columns ?

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's working.

Answer (score 3):

This error is likely produced by the npm db-migrate, and it just calls the floating point number data type `real` instead of float: http://github.com/db-migrate/shared/blob/master/data_type.js

Most database systems have a wide range of (sometimes synonymous) names for different data types. Postgres doesn't know `float`, but `float4` and `float8` which are synonyms for `real` and `double` respectively.

MySQL technically knows `float`, but that doesn't mean the db-migrate abstraction will accept is as input when run ... unless you find a way, that you can precisely define the data type, because you know about the target database ... which defeats the purpose of using an abstract tool for database migration anyway.

tl;dr: RTM for the tool you're using. Your tool (npm db-migrate) uses `real` instead of `float`.